# Prestashop - Which SQL called after actionProductUpdate?

Tags: prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.6

I try to update a `name` from `ps_product` when I update my product's stock. I added a SQL request on the hook `actionProductUpdate`.

The hook works, because when I set a `die;` after the SQL, the database is updated.

But I don't know where, another SQL is called and set back to the old value. I use `PROFILING` and I saw that it's called after....

How can I set this call as the last thing to do after a product update save ?

This is the simplified code :

```html
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
    $product = $params['product'];

    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product mp 
            SET mp.name = ''
            WHERE mp.id_product = ' . $product->id;

    Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);

}
```

PS : If I change a another parameter like `reference`, this time it works !

Comment: So strange, the docs says the "after saving the product" so it shouldn't be updated.

Have you tried with the hook: actionProductSave?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I don't understand... I tried too, but actionProductSave didn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use object product to achieve your goal. Something like

```
public function hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter($params)
{
    $product = new Product($params['object']->id);
    foreach(Language::getLanguages(true) as $language) {
        $product->name[$language['id_lang']] = 'new name';
    }
    $product->update();
}
```

in this case, you don't care where the name is persisted in the DB, and you will never damage it

PS : Take care of params if you want to get 'product'. In actionProductUpdate, it's params['product'] but in  hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter it's params['object'] (as Product). I lost so much time on this...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used name as exemple. Thanks for the tip, but I simplified my problem there. update() does the job but something keep calling after to erase my update...

Comment: Ok, try to use this hook hookActionObjectProductUpdateAfter instead of hookActionProductUpdate it is invoked after all product manipulations are done

Comment: Indeed, it's this hook, thanks you so much dude ! Let's post another reply with it, and I'll add some information about it if someone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

"name" field is in the "ps_product_lang" table.

You have to rename product for each languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used name as exemple. The fact is that the rename works but an unknown call come after and erase my modifications...